# JavaFX HBox Border

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I don´t understand why there is no border around my HBox? Nothing happens now exceptly eclipse throwing a IllegalArgumentException because of the this.setCenter(hbox) part I guess. (Ignore this, I am just writing because StackOverflow don´t allow me otherwise to upload this amount of code)

```
package view;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class MyPane extends BorderPane{

private int score=0;

public MyPane() {
    this.score=0;
    init();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyPane(int score) {
    this.score=score;
    init();
}

public void init() {

    Image img=new Image("Ball.png");
    ImageView imv= new ImageView(img);
    imv.setFitHeight(100);
    imv.setFitWidth(100);
    Label label= new Label(Integer.toString(score));
    label.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    label.setFont(new Font(50));
    label.setPadding(new Insets(18));



    HBox hbox= new HBox();
    hbox.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null , null)));
    hbox.getChildren().add(imv);
    hbox.getChildren().add(label);
    hbox.setSpacing(50);
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));






    this.getChildren().add(hbox);
    this.setCenter(hbox);
}
```

}

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here. The border appears just fine for me.

Comment: That being said, it's likely much easier to add a border using CSS: `hbox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");`

Comment: `
public class MyPane extends BorderPane{
 
 
 
 
 public void init() {
  
  
  
  Label label= new Label(Integer.toString(score));
  label.setPrefSize(100, 100);
  label.setFont(new Font(50));
  label.setPadding(new Insets(18));
  
  
  
  HBox hbox= new HBox();
  hbox.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null , null)));
  hbox.getChildren().add(label);
  hbox.setSpacing(50);
  hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
  
  
  
 
 
  
  this.getChildren().add(hbox);
  
 }
 
}`

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to add the `HBox` as an "unmanaged" child of your `BorderPane`. With a `BorderPane`, you must specify which ***region*** you want the `Node` to be placed in.

Therefore, the problem isn't that your border isn't showing up on the `HBox`, it's that your `HBox` is never actually being added to your `BorderPane`.

Change your last line to:

`this.setCenter(hbox);`

This will set your `HBox` in the center of the `BorderPane`.

Please review the documentation for [`BorderPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) for more information.

Comment: I changed the last line to this.setCenter(hbox); but it still don´t work :C It throws now an exception for illegal argument

Comment: Then please edit your question and provide the [mcve] I mentioned in my first comment. You have more than just this one problem.

Comment: How do I do this? ^^ sry I am new

Comment: Just read the link I posted? Then click the "edit" link under your question. The basic idea is for you to provide enough code that I can copy and test on my system so I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is it enough now?

Comment: You didn't change the last line, you just added a new one. :) You can't try to add the `hbox` twice. Remove the line: `this.getChildren().add(hbox);`